# Handle multiple conditions before running a BigQuery job using a scheduled query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I plan to have a scheduled query in BigQuery where it run the some query to check for some conditions first. Then, if all condition passed, it will run the aggregation query.

What I can think of right now is to do something like this:

```
declare A default (select count(*) from mydataset.mytable);  --SELECT query to get a value
declare B ...
declare C ... 
. . . -- get all of the value into a variable

-- Then use if-else condition e.g.
if A > 100 and B = C+D+E and B = F and ...
then
   -- run an aggregation queries
else
   select "not pass the condition"; -- don't run anything
end if;
```

This way is workable but I want to make it more visible when some condition is not met. I can view later what condition is not passed. Any idea to improve this when running in scheduled query?

Comment: does all your conditions (`A`,`B`,...) return integers ?
If you want to know specifically which condition hasn't passed, you have to make multiple if-self instead of using `and`s . Have you tried this ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva haven't try that yet but seem to be interesting. For now I just use `RAISE USING MESSAGE` in the else condition to make it error if its not pass all. I think I can adapt your idea to filter each condition e.g. if A != B, then raise using message "A not equal B", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the use of the raise and multiple conditional tests to specify the specific error you can use the following:

```sql
BEGIN
    DECLARE A DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ds.table`);
    DECLARE B DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ds.table`);

    DECLARE C1 DEFAULT A>1;
    DECLARE C2 DEFAULT B>A;

    IF C1 AND C2 THEN
        SELECT "Execute Query";
    ELSE 
        IF NOT (C1) THEN raise USING message="Condition 1 failed"; END IF;
        IF NOT (C2) THEN raise USING message="Condition 2 failed"; END IF;
    END IF; 

EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN 
    SELECT @@error.message;
END;
```

[image]
[image]

But if you will have multiple faillling conditions, its better to use a select:

```sql
    DECLARE A DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ds.table`);
    DECLARE B DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ds.table`);

    DECLARE C1 DEFAULT A>10;
    DECLARE C2 DEFAULT B>A;

    IF C1 AND C2 THEN
        SELECT "Execute Query";
    ELSE 
        IF NOT (C1) THEN select "Condition 1 failed"; END IF;
        IF NOT (C2) THEN select "Condition 2 failed"; END IF;
    END IF;
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah if its fail, most likely multiple condition will fail. By doing the second way, the query will still run successfully. Can we some how concat all the failed condition and raise at the end?

Comment: Oh I just think that we can declare a result variable (default Null) then if there's a failed condition, I can set a variable and concat itself and at last check if this variable still null or not if not (mean that there's some failed condition occurred) then raise the error